# How can I find the percentage of something in a column of dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Volcano Name': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'e'],
                   'Start Year': [1960, 1962, 1961, 1961, 1961, 1960, 1959, 1959, 1958, 1960, 1958],
                   'VEI': [0.0, 3.0,3.0,2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0],
                   'Lat': [31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31]})
```

How can I find the percentage of each volcano by VEI? there were similar question here but couldn't figure out how to implement in mine.

I guess I should start by something like

```
df.groupby('VEI').count()

or

df.pivot_table( index=['Volcano Name','VEI'], columns='Volcano Name')
```

thank you

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: How does the VEI maps on such percentage? It is not clear exactly what the formula would be...

Comment: For percentage of `Vulacano Name` grouped by `VEI`: `df.groupby('VEI')['Volcano Name'].apply(pd.Series.value_counts, {'normalize':True})`? But it's hard to tell if this is what you want.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny thank you, almost what I needed. My data was a sample of bigger data. your code did work. however I can't get the information for a specified 'volcano name'. it returns this error.  grouped.get_group('a')  >>  AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_group'

Answer (score 1):

This snippet groups your data entries by volcano name, sums up the VEI for each volcano and calculates the percentage of this value based on the sum/all VEI values. This might not be exactly what you want (see comments to your question), but the approach can hopefully and easily be adjusted to your needs.

```
sum_vei = df["VEI"].sum()
result = 100*df.groupby('Volcano Name')["VEI"].sum()/sum_vei)
```